# Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History' with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

After I `run-build` cause an error, it seems to be wrong in the 'react-router' or something.
When pressing the login button, it causes an error.

[image]

```
return (
  this.state.getuser != null &&
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <LoginRoute exact path="/" component={LoginPage} />
      <SystemRoute exact path="/home" component={HomePage} />
      <SystemRoute exact path="/order" component={OrderPage} />
      <SystemRoute exact path="/cook" component={CookPage} />
      <SystemRoute exact path="/getmoney" component={GetmoneyPage} />
      <SystemRoute exact path="/managemenu" component={ManageMunu} />
      <SystemRoute exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
      <Route component={LoginPage} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
)
```

Login component

```
render() {
    if (this.state.login) { return <Redirect to='/home' /> }
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            ...jsx...
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
}
```